# Changing parameter position in sql builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

i am using report builder to generate charts in sharepoint. I am using parameters to filter the data in the chart. When i view the report in the page viewer in the sharepoint site the filter is displaying in the right hand side of the page. Is there any option to change the filter to the top of the page??

Answer (score 0):

Not with Report Builder. There isn't anything there to control the parameters display location. To do this, you'll need to use Report Designer.